# Connect to postgreSQL db using PHP on mac os X

Tags: php, pdo, psql, yum

I tried to connect to a local postgre Database with PDO using PHP.

1. When running my code, the error message showed: `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in {file path}`
2. After googling, it looks like updating the PDO extension is a way fixing it.

   Then I tried to use the code [here](https://gist.github.com/giorgiofellipe/6282df335fd310de4108).
3. When executing line 21 `./configure --with-pdo-pgsql="/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/"`
   , the error message is shown:
   `configure: error: Cannot find libpq-fe.h. Please specify correct PostgreSQL installation path`
   p.s. I check the setting of my Postgres, the paths are shown below, do I need to change path to one of those?

[image: setting]

4. Then I googled for the error again. There are a number of post indicate that using `yum -y install postgresql-devel`
5. But the error shows again when I tried to run the code: `-bash: yum: command not found`

This is a confusing journey of PHP beginner tried to figure out getting data from a database using

PHP. Can someone provide a way to do achieve this (On Mac) ?

Comment: Hi you don't have def or yum on MAC. The simple way to install is, you use Porstgres.app https://postgresapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when changing my local server from xampp to mapp.